# What is the difference between using $1 vs \1 in Perl regex substitutions?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm debugging some code and wondered if there is any practical difference between $1 and \1 in Perl regex substitutions

For example:

```
my $package_name = "Some::Package::ButNotThis";

$package_name =~ s{^(\w+::\w+)}{$1};  

print $package_name; # Some::Package
```

This following line seems functionally equivalent:

```
$package_name =~ s{^(\w+::w+)}{\1};
```

Are there subtle differences between these two statements? Do they behave differently in different versions of Perl?

Comment: Perhaps related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890700/backreferences-syntax-in-replacement-strings-why-dollar-sign

Comment: If you run with `use warnings` enabled (and you absolutely should), your second example will produce a warning: `\1 better written as $1 ...`.

Comment: Casual observation: the regex substitution doesn't alter the string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you should always use [warnings](http://search.cpan.org/warnings.html) when developing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $package_name = "Some::Package::ButNotThis";

$package_name =~ s{^(\w+::\w+)}{\1};

print $package_name, "\n";
```

Output:

```
\1 better written as $1 at C:\Temp\x.pl line 7.
```

When you get a warning you do not understand, add [diagnostics](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html):

```
C:\Temp> perl -Mdiagnostics x.pl
\1 better written as $1 at x.pl line 7 (#1)
    (W syntax) Outside of patterns, backreferences live on as variables.
    The use of backslashes is grandfathered on the right-hand side of a
    substitution, but stylistically it's better to use the variable form
    because other Perl programmers will expect it, and it works better if
    there are more than 9 backreferences.
```

Why does it work better when there are more than 9 backreferences? Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $t = (my $s = '0123456789');
my $r = join '', map { "($_)" } split //, $s;

$s =~ s/^$r\z/\10/;
$t =~ s/^$r\z/$10/;

print "[$s]\n";
print "[$t]\n";
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> x
]
[9]
```

If that does not clarify it, take a look at:

```
C:\Temp> x | xxd
0000000: 5b08 5d0d 0a5b 395d 0d0a                 [.]..[9]..
```

See also [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators):

> The following escape sequences are available in constructs that interpolate and in transliterations …

`\10` octal is `8` decimal. So, the replacement part contained the character code for [`BACKSPACE`](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html).

#### NB

Incidentally, your code does not do what you want: That is, it will *not* print `Some::Package` some package contrary to what your comment says because all you are doing is replacing `Some::Package` with `Some::Package` without touching `::ButNotThis`.

You can either do:

```
($package_name) = $package_name =~ m{^(\w+::\w+)};
```

or

```
$package_name =~ s{^(\w+::\w+)(?:::\w+)*\z}{$1};
```

Comment: And if you want a laugh, you'll also install [warnin's](http://wonkden.net/modules.html). :)

Answer (score 8):

From [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> > The bracketing construct "( ... )" creates capture buffers. To refer to
> >            the current contents of a buffer later on, within the same pattern, use
> >            \1 for the first, \2 for the second, and so on.  Outside the match use
> >            "$" instead of "\".

The `\<digit>` notation works in certain circumstances outside the match. But it can potentially clash with octal escapes. This happens when the backslash is followed by more than 1 digits.

Comment: If you have at least one capture buffer within the regex, whatever was previously stored in $1 will be overwritten.

Comment: It should be noted that in a replacement (`s/.../.../`), the first part is a match, the second is not.