# Notepad++ Regex Replace doesn't work on Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I tried to search for every word that has 
bar-foo and switch them to foo-bar 
so I wrote on the find `(\w+)-(\w+)` 
and on the replace `$2-$1` 
and instead of writing foo-bar it wrote $2-$1.

Yes, Regular Expression in search mode is on. 
It seems that the Replace Regex doesn't work and been taken literally

Comment: How is SO less appropriate of a place to answer this question than SU?

Comment: who said it was less appropriate ? I guess it's a borderline topic, since notepad++ is used 99% for programming.. and Regex could be considered as programming... dunno :I

Comment: I was referring to the two people who voted to move to Super User.

Comment: ***Update:*** For Notepad++ version 6.0 or newer (=> 6.0), you can use `\1` **and** `$1` [(a detailed explanation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970405/notepad-backreference-regex-syntax-in-search-replace-1-or-1/11970406#11970406).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

With notepad++ you'll need to use `\2-\1` as the replacement string.

**Sources :**
[Mark's Speechblog](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: For instance, why when I try to search for (empty|isset) it doesn't find anything although there's 'empty' inside the doc?

Answer (score 9):

Use `\2 \1` in the replace field.

[Notepad++ uses the linux like \1 syntax instead of $1](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions#Example_1)