# Notepad++ Regex Backreference syntax in Search/Replace - \1 or $1

Tags: regex, escaping, notepad++, replace, backreference

I have tried to use the Notepad++ Search/Replace with a Regular Expression to replace specific words with shorter versions of those words.

---

I used the following regex to match every word that ends with `er` (but not `er` as a word) - and replace the matching words with the same words minus the ending `r`, using a backreference:

*`Find what:`* **`([a-zA-z]+e)r`**

*`Replace with:`* **`$1`**

But it doesn't replace the matching words, even though it finds them.

**However, if I change the backreference syntax to this:**

*`Replace with:`* **`\1`**

Everything works fine.

---

Why doesn't the `$1` backreference work?

What is the difference between the two forms of the backrefernce - `\1` and `$1`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Notepad++'s earlier versions (v5.9.8 and prior) only supported standard [POSIX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) Regular Expressions. However, full [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) Search/Replace support was added in version 6.0:

> [New features and enhancement in Notepad++ 6.0:](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html)
>
> - PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) is supported.

This means that if you're using Notepad++ v6.0 or any newer version (e.g v6.1.5), you can use the PCRE syntax, and use `$1` instead of `\1` for backreference, but it won't be compatible with earlier versions of Notepad++ (prior to version 6.0). Other than that, they're similar.

For more info regarding the differences between the backreference syntax and the reasons behind the new syntax support, see [**Backreferences syntax in replacement strings (why dollar sign?)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890700/backreferences-syntax-in-replacement-strings-why-dollar-sign).

A useful tutorial on how to use regular expressions in Notepad++ can be found [**here**](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions).

Comment: @amiregelz I've been using (and loving) Notepad++ for many years, but one of the biggest frustrations I've had with it has been its poor Regex support. I can't believe I've been in the dark on these enhancements for TWO YEARS. Standard back-references, zero-width assertions -- it's beautiful! Thank you for opening my eyes!

Comment: - yup doing things like searching for consecutive lines that start with same word etc. It rocks ;-) `(searchtext)[^\n]*\n\1`