# NetBeans replace all constants using regular expression

Tags: regex, netbeans, replace

I'm using NetBeans and I want to know what regular expression to use to add single/double quotes around each constant. Every constant is defined like this:

```
define(SYSTEM_BASEDIR, '/base/dir');
```

Afaik, that is not the correct way. I need to convert all constants to this:

```
define('SYSTEM_BASEDIR', '/base/dir');
```

Thanks in advance to all helpers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct that `define(SYSTEM_BASEDIR, '/base/dir');` is invalid syntax since you are using the constant before defining it.

Now for the regex:

Open up the Replace Dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

Find What: `define\((\w*),`

Replace With: `define("$1",`

This will turn this:

```
define(BLA,"test");
```

into:

```
define("BLA","test");
```

Comment: @GungFoo No need to escape `,`

Comment: Neither to escape `(` on the replacment string.

Answer (score 4):

Netbeans `Ctrl`+`H`

```
find: (define\()(\w*)(\,)
replace: define("$2",
```

check Regular expression

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\bdefine\((\w+),/', 'define(\'\1\',', $subject);
```

changes all instances of

```
define(<alphanumeric word>,
```

into

```
define('<alphanumeric word>',
```

Comment: @GungFoo: Stylock asked how to replace all constants in PHP, he tagged the question PHP, and this is a Q&A site for programming questions. So I naturally assumed he was looking for a PHP solution.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

```
find: define\(([A-Za-z_]+),
replace: define('$1',
```

check Regular expression

Answer (score 1):

From your editor find replace text

use this reg expression there :

```
find : define\((.*),

replace : define('\$1',
```

If your are using notepad++

```
replace : define('\1',
```

Comment: @NaveedS :  Have you tried it? it works for me in notepad++ (I am not sure about net beans, but i guess it will work)

Comment: `\1` can't be used for capture group reference in replacement string, but it can be used for backreference inside the regex. It worked in Notepad++ due to difference in the supported regex standard. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970405/notepad-regex-backreference-syntax-in-search-replace-1-or-1

Answer (score 0):

replace using this regex

```
(?<constant>(?:[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)*))
```