# How to remove a space between two characters or strings in notepad++

Tags: regex

Consider I have a string in quotations `"( the"` which occures in a huge body of text.

I want to remove the space between non-alphanumeric `(` and aplphanumeric `t` characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace match of regular expression pattern `(?<=\()\s+(?=t)` with empty string.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If any alphanumeric character may occur after such space, then use pattern `(?<=\()\s+(?=[^\W_])`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: It does exactly what I wanted. Namely, it matches only the space between the characters excluding the characters.

Comment: @Coddy - `(?<=...)` is lookbehind, `(?=...)` is lookahead. I have updated my answer with diagrams, that should help you to understand it a little bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970406/3025921) if you are using version 6.0 or later you can use Perl compatible regular expressions.  So you could do the following regex search and replace.

```
replace (\W) (\w) with \1\2
replace (\w) (\W) with \1\2
```

This will remove the space between any non-alphanumeric and alphnumeric characters first, then the reverse (alnum, space, non-alnum).

Comment: It does match the space but the match includes the characters too that surround the space. It should only match the space.

Comment: But when you replace it with \1\2 you are putting back the surrounding characters, effectively removing only the space.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex find/replace will do it for all, not only `( t` occurrences:

Find: `\( ([a-zA-Z])`

Replace: `\(\1`

Remember to check *Regular expression* on the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: It does match the space but the match includes the characters too that surround the space. It should only match the space.