# Surround strings with quotes in Notepad++ using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have below text line in Notepad ++

```
Type, Layer, Env, key, action, timestamp, performedBy, desc,
```

I want to convert it to

```
'Type', 'Layer', 'Env', 'key', 'action', 'timestamp', 'performedBy', 'desc',
```

I write in find `[a-zA-Z]*`, and it gives me each comma separated string what shall I enter in replace to have them surrounded by quotes?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `([a-zA-Z]*)` in find and  `'\1'` or `'$1'` in replace.

`\1` or `$1` (in newer versions of n++) means the first captured group.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970405/notepad-regex-backreference-syntax-in-search-replace-1-or-1/11970406).

Comment: I needed to include numbers and a period, so `([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)` worked for me, having * means "empty" matches are included also which in my case didn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$0` to refer to the whole match in the replacement pattern, so you could handle your task simply by replacing with :

```
'$0'
```

Additionally, I suggest changing your matching pattern to `[a-zA-Z]+` instead of `[a-zA-Z]*` to avoid the risk of adding quotes around zero-width matches.

Answer (score 3):

If you search for `([a-zA-Z]*),` the `()` indicates a group you can reference later.

Now you can write `'$1',` in the replace dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find What: `(.*?)(?=,)`
  Replace With: '$1'

Output: 'Type',' Layer',' Env',' key',' action',' timestamp',' performedBy',' desc',

Note: Make sure Search Mode is Regular expression

Comment: This would work except the output should not have a space within the quotes. Bad: ' bla', ' ble' - Good: 'bla', 'ble'.