# Java: Replace substring with <b>substring</b> case insensitive

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

I'm making an app that searches a database - I want the search term to be bolded in my output. Suppose I have a string:

```
String s = "Foo Bar foobAr"; 
String searchTerm = "bar";
```

now, I want to surround every occurance of searchTerm in my string s with   (to make it bold) regardless of case. Output should be:

```
"Foo <b>Bar</b> foo<b>bAr</b>"
```

[This is relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054995/how-to-replace-case-insensitive-literal-substrings-in-java), but it makes the output the same as the searchTerm - I want to preserve the casing of the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use back-referencing to replace the string you want. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890700/backreferences-syntax-in-replacement-strings-why-dollar-sign) for more explanations about back-referencing.

Taking that into account, this should do the trick:

```
s.replaceAll("(?i)(" + searchTerm + ")", "<b>$1</b>")
```

Comment: Yeap thats it, just change to `s.replaceAll...` not `searchTerm.replaceAll`