# Regex - Actual working example (with limitation) of capturing HTML tags with custom class name

Tags: html, regex

So I was searching for ways to match and replace any html tag with a specific class name, but it seemed that, as I feared, [it's not possible with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) (at least not perfectly).

However, I decided to code a solution that would fit my needs, but I figured out a way to actually match tags of the same level with this pattern :

**/`^(\t*)<([^>]{1,10}) [^>]*class="(?:[^"]+\s|)myclass.*".*>(.*)^\1<\/\2>`/gUsm**

([depending on your language, you may use `\` or `$`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890700/backreferences-syntax-in-replacement-strings-why-dollar-sign) to identify a [backreference](https://sodocumentation.net/regex/topic/4072/back-reference))

I tested it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) (with *global*, *Ungreedy*, *single line* and *multi line* options enabled) and used this html code :

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <div id="foo" class="chosemyclass" data="stuff" >
        <div>Hello World!</div>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="nombinouche" class="chose myclass" data="stuff" >
        <div>Hello World!</div>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="bleh" class="myclass bob" data="moar">
        <div>Hello World!</div>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
<a class="chose myclass" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8PxqgliIno" >
    <a>Hello World!</a>
    <span>of course it's a rickroll</span>
</a>
<a>
</a>
    <div><h1 class="myclass">This content can't be captured because the tag doesn't start after the indentation
    </h1></div>
<h1 class="myclass">This content can't be captured because the tag ends on the same line</h1>
<h1 class="myclass">However it captures it if the next line does
</h1>
```

I use the **2nd capture group** to return the **tag**, the **3rd** to return its **content** and use the **1st capture group** is used to match the **same indentation preceding the opening tag**.

What each part does:

- `^(\s*)` make the difference between its own closing tag and its children's closing tags (only when starting a line)
- `<([^>]{1,10})`  identifies the html tag [(longest being 10 characters)](https://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_longest_HTML_tag_name#answer_33431626) which doesn't close immediately
- `[^>]*class="` verifies if it has a class before the tag closes
- `(?:[^"]+\s|)` verifies if it has another class before the desired class and if not, makes sure there's a whitespace before the desired class (so you don't end up selecting `otherstuff` when searching `stuff`)
- `myclass.*".*>` searches for your class name and confirms the end of the opening tag
- `(.*)` returns the tag's content
- `^\1<\/\2>` verifies if the indentation at the start of a line and the closing tag matches the opening

*but...*

While this pattern fits my needs, it isn't perfect:

- It is absolutely not working with minified code
- It might not work or recognize the correct tag if the code is not well indented (check out [DirtyMarkup](https://www.10bestdesign.com/dirtymarkup/) if it helps)
- Tags that end one the same line are not recognized (though I'm sure this can be remedied in RegEx)
- Unrecognized tags' content **and** closing tag such as above will be wrongly returned as content if a later tag of the same indentation is correctly recognized.

Can you extrapolate on my solution?

Comment: _"it's not possible with RegEx"_ ... _"However, I decided to code a [regex] solution"_ ... _"but... it isn't perfect: ... It is absolutely not working ... It might not work or recognize ... are not recognized ... wrongly returned as content ..."_ - Just use a `DOMParser` o.O

Comment: Why is this tagged with `php`?

Comment: DOMParser is good, but it's not as compatible as with RegEx and it's not possible in the instance I'm using it (being a php function for a plugin)
I removed the js tag

Comment: I felt like this was concerning php too because this is the language I'm using rn, but you're right, php is too large to be really meaningful to the question